# What is small according to microsoft? `cryptprotectdata` data upper limit

Tags: c#, passwords, buffer, cryptprotectdata, local-security-authority

In the [documentation about the CryptProtectData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 
function Microsoft tells to only use `CryptProtectData` with small buffers.

> This call can be slow and a memory hog, and unreliable. Use only with
>   small buffers.
>
> CryptProtect/UnprotectData makes a call across RPC to the LSA where
>   the actual encryption or decryption is done **and RPC has upper limits
>   on how much data can be passed**. A general rule of thumb for encryption
>   of large amounts of data is to protect the bulk with a symmetric key
>   and then protect the symmetric key using CryptProtectData. Decryption
>   is just a reversal and you’ll find better performance (avoid costly
>   RPC operations) and are usually just as secure (dependent on symmetric
>   algorithm used for the large block of data).

So what is this upper limit? Can I secure multiple passwords with a length of 256 Byte each with it?

Comment: That's not necessarily part of the documentation. That blurb is something added by a Social user. I don't see a way of knowing exactly what is "small" since it was one person's unknown definition of "small". But I would infer it means, "use with a paragraph sized string, not the entire newspaper".

Comment: ProtectedData as the DPAPI wrapper in C# does not make any assumptions about the size of data to protect in the more official version of the documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx